# Remove Target in Rails name, not link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, field, erb, target

I'm sending my users a update e-mail when one of their documents gets updated using a mailer.  The problem is, I'm referencing the recipient in the update email - and the only information I have on them is their e-mail address.  If the user gets the email as it's written, there is a link in the email body:

Update_email.html.erb

```
<br>
    <%= @document.recipient %> has completed and signed the <%= @document.template.name %> you sent them.<br> <br>
    Please log in to to view it.
    <br><br>
    Thanks,<br>
```

and the user gets something that looks like this:

> [foo@foo.com](http://#) has completed and signed the 'document' you sent them.
>        Please log in to view it.

However, the typical `target: '_blank'` syntax doesn't seem to work.

Anyone have any idea how to pass the blank target to a ruby field like above?

Comment: What link? What you are seeing is just that your email client looks for email addresses and wraps them in `<a href="mailto:test@example.com">test@example.com</a>` however exactly how that happens is up to the client.

Comment: No,  I'm not trying to create a link. When I send the email, a link is created in the message. It may be the email client (receiving end) creating the link because it sees an email address.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I said. However your question still does not specify what you actually want. If you can explain from a non technical standpoint that might help. `When the user opens the email and clicks the recipients email he should ...`